# How do I tokenize array of json objects?

Tags: java, json, jsp, struts, tokenize

Hi I need to tokenize an array of json objects but I'm not sure how to go about doing that.

Currently, I have this snippet:

```
StringTokenizer tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(request, "{}:,\"");
Map<String, String> properties = new HashMap<String, String>();
while(tokenizer.hasMoreTokens()) {
    String key = tokenizer.nextToken(); 
    String value = tokenizer.nextToken();
    properties.put(key, value);
}
```

This snippet allows me to tokenize a regular (non-complex) json object so that I can get the value using the key as the lookup. However, it does not work for complex objects in the form like `[{"Foo":"Bar", "XYZ":12}, {"ABC":16, "Foo": "Bar"}...]`

So I was wondering how can I tokenize an array of json objects?

Comment: Is there any reason to not use an existing library to do this job?

Comment: @ngueno I'm maintaining legacy code and I can't add new libraries to code. Is there something else I can use in Java 1.6?

Comment: unfortunately Java does not provide any meaninful tool like Gson  or Jackson, I do not think it is a good idea to write a JSON parser by hand on your project. The mentioned libraries are well tested and have a lot of community support.

Comment: Writing a JSON parser is more irritating than you think it is. There's no native support for JSON in Java 1.6 (EOLed even with an extended support package in 2018). The notion that you can't add a library is... a foolish decision by whoever made it, because adding a known-good library is *far* less risk than having to maintain your own JSON parser.

Answer (score 0):

Regex is not suitable for parsing or tokenizing JSON. Instead parse JSON with a parser e.g. [Gson](https://github.com/google/gson):

```
String json = "[{\"Foo\":\"Bar\", \"XYZ\":12}, {\"ABC\":16, \"Foo\": \"Bar\"}]";
Map<String, String>[] result = new Gson().fromJson(json, new TypeToken<Map<String, String>[]>() {}.getType());
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(result));
```

will output below showing two `Map` objects:

```
[{Foo=Bar, XYZ=12}, {ABC=16, Foo=Bar}]
```

Comment: I don't have access to Gson. I'm maintaining legacy code and I can't add new libraries to code. Is there something else I can use in Java 1.6?